# How to calculate an average, skipping blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average, blank-line

I have a spreadsheet, where I keep the times I come in and leave at and from work.
In the next column, I summarise those values in order to see the amount of time I spent at work, which gives me the amount of time I spent at work during a week.

Now I'd like to know what is the average time I spent at work during a week.

I'd thought I could achieve this using the `AVERAGEIF` function, using `">0"` in order to skip blank entries, but this seems not to work:

E.g.

```
        A          B           C     D      E     F
1       Day        Date        In    Out    Diff  Cumul
2       Monday     13/10/2014  8:15  16:30  7:30  
3       Tuesday    14/10/2014  8:15  17:10  8:10  
4       Wednesday  15/10/2014  8:05  17:10  8:20  
5       Thursday   16/10/2014  8:25  17:10  8:00  
6       Friday     17/10/2014  8:25  17:00  7:50  
7       Saturday   18/10/2014                     39:50
```

As you see, column E contains the difference between "In" and "Out" (taking into account the lunch break), column F contains the sum of the values of column E.

For calculating the average of the entries in column F, I've tried to use the function "AVERAGEIF", as follows:

```
=AVERAGEIF(F1:F7;">0") // I thought of ">0" for skipping blanks,
                       //  and so only use cells which are filled in.
```

The result of this function however is 15:50 (no idea how to interpret this), afterwards I'd like to replace "F1:F7" by "F:F" for calculating the average of the whole sheet.

There are two solutions to my problem:

- either tell the `AVERAGEIF` formula only to use the cells F7, F14, F21, ... (is this even possible?)
- either keep on using the "F:F" range but use another condition than ">0" for skipping blanks, I think this is the easiest solution.

Does anybody know how to skip blanks in formulas?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that your issue isn't caused by blanks, but by Excel converting a number to a time value. Format the cell as "number" instead.

Comment: `15:50` is actually the same as `39:50` in your case. It only shows the hours of a day. So it is 1 Day and 15:50 which equals 39:50, but the 24 hours of the day are not shown due to formatting. So it is most probably only a problem with your formatting.

Comment: Do you have any formula in the cells F2-F6 (or generally Monday-Friday) or do you only have some Sum-Formula in the Saturday-Rows? Since `=AVERAGE(...)` does ignore empty cells by default (see [AVERAGE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGE-function-047BAC88-D466-426C-A32B-8F33EB960CF6) 3rd point under Remarks) you might only use `=AVERAGE(F:F)` to calculate the average. Keep in mind that excel stores time values as "percent of a day" so `12:00:00 = 0.5` and `24:00:00 = 1` and `39:50:00 = 1.65972`.

Comment: If the result shows something unexpected (just like `15:50`) this is due to the formatting. You might just format your cell containing the average the same as your Saturday-Cumul-Cells and it should look correct to you. If you have any formula in your Monday-Friday cells in column F then please post that formula and I'll help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has correctly been given by Fabian F, thanks a lot for that. The situation is the following:

I had forgotten that the cells in Column F had a special formatting `[u]:mm`, causing `39:50` to be correctly shown as `39:50`, in normal cases this gets translated into `15:50` (you can't fit `39:50` hours in a day, hence `39:50-24:00=15:50`).

It seems that blanks are skipped automatically by the `AVERAGE` function, so my request to skip blanks has no sense.

However, I'll keep using the formula as you can see in following template of next week:

```
        A           B  C  D  E      F
Monday     07/11/2016               
Tuesday    08/11/2016               
Wednesday  09/11/2016               
Thursday   10/11/2016               
Friday     11/11/2016               
Saturday   12/11/2016           0:00
```

As you see, column F contains sums (of empty values), hence this contains a zero value. By using the `AVERAGEIF` function with condition `">0"`, I can skip the templates of the weeks which are not filled in yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply supply the relevant cells to the formula if they aren't going to change location:

```
=AVERAGE(F7;F14;F21)
```

Cells given do not have to be contiguous.

Comment: That's an idea, indeed, but how can I continue this until the end of the sheet? The idea is to have a formula, calculating the average of F7, F14, F21, ... but as you see at the three dots, go on until the end of the page, and by skipping the blanks, I'd hoped to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues once or twice with it not skipping blanks, particularly on reports that have blanks that aren't really blank.

To be safe I use

```
{=AVERAGEIF(IF(ISNUMBER(F:F),A:A)}
```